# How many ways to pick a committee of 5, out of 12 seniors and 8 juniors, which contains at least 3 seniors and 1 junior?

Tags: combinatorics

This is my reasoning:

First we choose 3 seniors out of 12, then we choose 1 junior out of 8, then we have 12 - 3 + 8 - 1 = 16 students left. The last spot can be taken by either a senior or junior so we choose 1 out of 16. Hence there are $ { 12 \choose 3 } { 8 \choose 1 } { 16 \choose 1} = 28160  $ combinations.

However, this is the solution:

We can have either 4 seniors and 1 junior or 3 seniors and 2 juniors. So the total number of combinations is $ { 12 \choose 4 }{ 8 \choose 1} + {12\choose 3}{8 \choose2} = 10120. $

Where did my reasoning go wrong?

Comment: Your method counts ABCjD, ABDjC, ACDjB, and BCDjA separately. These are all the same committee, ABCDj, counted four times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are double counting. Notice that when you split your sets like that, suppose there is a senior called $A,$ there is the possibility that you have chosen $A$ using your $\binom{12}{3}$ as some of those members. But also, there is the possibility that you chose $A$ as the person in the remaining $16.$ When, in the right answer, they completely split the sum into two sums in which the people of each group is chosen, they eliminate that possibility.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to account for that by subtracting 3 seniors chosen in the first step from 12 to get 9 and the 1 junior chosen in the second step from 8 to get 7 for a total of 16 remaining students, could you explain why that didn't eliminate the possibility of double counting?

Comment: @Imperator1550 I agree that the senior would not be twice in the group. But the problem is that the configuration is counted twice because. What if you pick your $3$ people(without the senior) and then the senior. That is one way but you could have computed the same set of people by first choosing the senior and then not choosing it.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense now. Is there any way to figure out how many times I've double counted or is the given solution the only way to solve this problem?

Comment: @Imperator1550  You have counted each case in which there are four seniors and one junior four times, once for each of the $\binom{4}{3}$ ways you could have designated three of the four seniors as the three seniors on the committee, and each case in which there are three seniors and two juniors twice, once for each of the $\binom{2}{1}$ ways you could have designated one of the two juniors as the junior on the committee.  Notice that $$\color{red}{\binom{4}{3}}\binom{12}{4}\binom{8}{1} + \color{red}{\binom{2}{1}}\binom{12}{3}\binom{8}{2} = \color{red}{28160}$$